# how to convert a qiskit circuit to pauli strings

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit

I have a qiskit quantum circuit that i want to convert to pauli strings (coefficients,observables) so that i can use it to build a hamiltonian. I did not see any methods in qiskit quantumcircuit library to do that. I can transpile the circuit to qasm format but i don't know how to build a hamiltonian from that. Any solution? thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to QCSE. Hamiltonians in general need not be unitary only Hermetian. I'm not sure what you mean by converting a circuit to a Hamiltonian. 
Are you asking... How can I write my circuit as a sequence of exponentiated Pauli strings? $e^{iHt}$ is unitary for a Hamiltonian $H$.